Calling a COM server from a C# client
How do I call the methods of an out-of-process COM server from within a C# program? The COM server is implemented in a C++/MFC program which is already running when the C# code is invoked. Sorry if this is a very basic question, and maybe I didn't use the best search keywords.
I can do this in PowerShell:
$obj = New-Object -ComObject MyComServer
$res = ""
$obj.RunScript('script_commands', [ref]$res);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComobject($obj)

where RunScript is declared in the *.idl file as
HRESULT RunScript(BSTR bsScript, [out] BSTR* pbsResult);
Now I want to do the same in C#. I tried
var obj_type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyComServer");
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(obj_type);
var res = obj_type.InvokeMember("RunScript", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static, null, obj, new object[] {"script_commands"});

After obj_type is assigned, its content is a System.__ComObject, which is probably to be expected. The CreateInstance call sits a long time waiting and finally throws an exception with the text "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {9BBEF959-EA98-11D3-8BC3-00A0C9CA04BF} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))." The GUID in this message matches the GUID specified in the *.idl file.
I assume that CreateInstance attempts to launch a second instance of the program that contains the COM server. This fails because the program prevents execution of two instances at one time. Looks like Activator.CreateInstance is a bad choice in this case?
Thank you for your help
Hans
--- EDIT ---
After some attempts with the help of the comments below (thank you everyone!), I found the following code to work in several situations:
var obj_type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyComServer");
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(obj_type);
string reply = "";
var ret = obj.RunScript("script_commands", ref reply);
Debug.WriteLine(reply);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);

These "several situations" are:

Either both server and client run elevated, or both don't run elevated. (Related post: Connect to an elevated COM server from a non-elevated process)
If the server is a 64-bit process, the client must also be a 64-bit process; no such restriction for a 32-bit server. (The reply in 32 bit COM client talking to 64 bit COM server and the other way around suggests otherwise)

I assume these are restrictions I'll have to live.

Remove BindingFlags.Static, a COM call is always an instance call. Otherwise, CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE means the COM server crashed or has issues. You can also try dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(obj_type); var res = obj.RunScript("script_commands"); (using C# dynamic keyword feature)

Thank you @SimonMourier. Maybe I was a bit unclear. I suspect that the call to Activator.CreateInstance created a second instance of the application which contains the COM server. This application contains code that prevents running a second instance, so the second instance shuts down immediately. This may have caused CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE. My question is, how to connect to an already existing instance?

It's a COM server problem, not a client issue. A COM server defines if it supports multiple clients or not, etc using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/ne-combaseapi-regcls and the rest is done by COM. That's not up to the client to handle that (or if it is then again the server is buggy)

Are you using .NET or .NET Framework?  What version? If unsure, see What is .NET Framework?, .NET Framework versions, and .NET versions.

@SimonMourier, thanks again for this valuable hint. The server calls RegisterClassObjects with CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER and REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE. But if the problem is on the server's side, I wonder why the sequence works in the PowerShell client?

@user246821 - using .NET framework 4.8 under Windows 11.

Don't know why it fails w/o a reproducing sample. I you have the server's code you should be able to understand what's going on. Have you tried with C# dynamic?

"long time waiting" is a signal.  Smells like security software getting in the way, often a problem when a .exe appears from seeming nowhere and does process interop right after it starts running.  Temporarily disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

The following may be of interest: CLSCTX enumeration
